# Objects within Object and assigning prototype

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have following object:

```
var level2blocks = {
    block1 : {
        left : 478,
        right : 515,
        up : 0,
        down : 510
    },
    block2 : {
        left : -10,
        right : 515,
        up : 373,
        down : 600
    }
};
```

I need to keep names of objects "block1" and "block2" since I call them in other functions, base on location of the player in html5-canvas. I also want to keep them inside object "level2blocks" since in the end I will have around 20 of these blocks.

If it possible to assign to block1 and block2 prototype, so I don't have to type all 4 parameters every time? this is the prototype I want to use:

```
var Block = function (left,right,up,down) {
    this.left = -10;
    this.right = 515;
    this.up = 0;
    this.down = 600;
}
```

So the idea is I will pass only for example 2 parameters like only left and down. And the missing values will be taken from prototype values.

For example:

```
   var level2blocks = {
        block1 : {
            left : 478,
            right : 515,
        },
        block2 : {
            left : -10,
            down : 600
        }
    };
```

And then in function when I call for `level2blocks.block1.down` it will refer to default value...

Comment: that's a constructor, not a proto. you don't want data on the prototype typically, because all instances would clobber each other's data. building own properties as you show is the right approach, then you can say `level2blocks ={block1: new Block}`

Comment: Maybe `function block(l, r, u, d){return {left:l, right:r, up:u, down:d}}` and then create "instances" without *new*: `var myNewBlock = block(-10,515,0,600)`. Probably a lot more efficient since you don't use the `[[prototype]]` anyway. Or maybe you will. Should *blocks* have common methods?

Comment: or a slight adjustment to RobG's code would let you skip defaults: `return{ left:l||200,right:r||120 ... }`

Comment: No common methods. I edit the description, since I missed the core point of my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below. `Block` is Class for inner blocks and `Level2blocks` is Class for managing those blocks. `Level2blocks` can have methods such as `add`, `remove` for inner `blocks`.

you can also use prototype values as default values in this case as i have done in `BlockProto` Class.

```js
function extend(obj, props) {
  for (var prop in props) {
    if (props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      obj[prop] = props[prop];
    }
  }
}

function Block(left, right, up, down) {
  this.left = left || -10; // for default values
  this.right = right || 515;
  this.up = up || 0;
  this.down = down || 600;
}

function BlockProto(obj) {
  extend(this, obj);
}

BlockProto.prototype.left = -10;
BlockProto.prototype.right = 515;
BlockProto.prototype.up = 0;
BlockProto.prototype.down = 600;

function Level2blocks() {
  this.blocks = {};
}

Level2blocks.prototype.addBlock = function(left, right, up, down) {
  var numOfBlocks = Object.keys(this.blocks).length;
  this.blocks['block' + numOfBlocks] = new Block(left, right, up, down);
};

Level2blocks.prototype.addPrototypeBlock = function(obj) {
  var numOfBlocks = Object.keys(this.blocks).length;
  this.blocks['block' + numOfBlocks] = new BlockProto(obj);
};

var level2Blocks = new Level2blocks();

level2Blocks.addBlock(2, 4, 2, 4);
level2Blocks.addBlock(123, 2, 090, 24);
level2Blocks.addBlock();
level2Blocks.addBlock(undefined, undefined, undefined, 900);

level2Blocks.addPrototypeBlock({});
level2Blocks.addPrototypeBlock({
  left: 4444
});


console.log(level2Blocks.blocks);
console.log(level2Blocks.blocks.block4.left);
console.log(level2Blocks.blocks.block4.right);

var HTMLStr = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(level2Blocks.blocks, 0, 4) + '</pre>';

HTMLStr += 'Block4 values from prototype: ';
HTMLStr += [level2Blocks.blocks.block4.right, level2Blocks.blocks.block4.left, level2Blocks.blocks.block4.up, level2Blocks.blocks.block4.down].join(', ');

HTMLStr += '<br/> Block5 values from prototype: ';
HTMLStr += [level2Blocks.blocks.block5.right, level2Blocks.blocks.block5.left, level2Blocks.blocks.block5.up, level2Blocks.blocks.block5.down].join(', ');

document.write(HTMLStr);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Wow. This is the proper answer. I will work with this today. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

```
var level2blocks = {
    block1: new Block(478, 515, 0, 510),
    block2: new Block(-10, 515, 373, 600)
};
```

Comment: You'll need to put a little more effort into your answer.